Reading a JSON file from a javascript file
so heres what happens,
i made a function that reads my JSON file, and at the end returns the value found
here are how my files are organized my files

and here is my script.js file
async function readJSONFile(path) {
    const [filePath, jsonPath] = path.split('|');

    try {
        const response = await fetch(filePath);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        const keys = jsonPath.split('/');
        let value = jsonData;
        for (const key of keys) {
            if (Array.isArray(value) && !isNaN(key)) {
                value = value[parseInt(key)];
            } else {
                value = value[key];
            }
            if (value === undefined || value === null) {
                return undefined;
            }
        }

        return value;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to read JSON file: ${error}`);// theres an error
        return undefined;
    }
}

const path = 'Items.json|Data/taxValue';
readJSONFile(path).then(result => console.log(result));  // Should print 1.15



as well as my JSON file if needed
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "taxValue": 1.15
        }
    ],
    "Fruits": [
        {
            "name": "apple",
            "cost": 1.59,
            "tax": true,
            "itemId": 12345,
            "ect...": 0
        }
    ],
    "Others": [

    ]
}

i was expecting to read the file but, i got an error,
'script.js:25 Failed to read JSON file: TypeError: Failed to fetch',
not sure how to fix, thats why im sking for help.

I think your filepath might be parsed in the wrong way. You might need a relative path to your json file, like this ./items.json.

The fetch request fails. I agree with @VanjaStojanović, the past is most probably incorrect. How do you load the script in your html?

I see that you are loading an html file in web browser and running some JavaScript to access a JSON file which is located in your file system. Browsers does not have capability to access the file system directly and also you just gave file name to the fetch API and it will just append the host as suffix to the file name that you passed ("file:///D:/some-dire/Items.json") where it fails to understand the path as it only supports http or https and not FTP which resulted  the error as "failed to fetch".
Possible solution:
Consider creating a dev server in Node JS which serves you both static files(index.html, style.css etc.) as well as any JSON files(Items.json) content over http or https using fetch API.
